# Mapped stored procedure with input XML parameter with Entity Framework

Tags: xml, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters, mapping

I have stored procedure with input parameter `@par XML`. When mapping and importing it in Entity Framework, `@par` type is set to `string`.

If I create this parameter like

```
XElement idPar = new XElement("root");
idPar.Add(new XElement("case", new XAttribute("IdCase", 100)));

e.InputParameters["par"] = idPar.ToString();
```

for `ObjectDataSource`

```
 <SelectParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="par" Type="Object" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

and get my par like string `"<root>\r\n  <case IdCase=\"100\" />\r\n</root>"` and my stored procedure does not work

When I used `DataSet` everything worked fine, and the parameter type mapped like XML not string

Any ideas?

How to force Entity Framework to work with stored procedure with XML input parameter?